# jQuery .click and .on('click' both not working even Javascript addEventHandler is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried everything, even using Javascript addEventHandler but still onclick is not working please check code and guide.
**I am trying click event on**

```
var z = y.find('td');
        //this is working fine
        z.hover(function () { $(this).addClass("hovereD"); }, function () { $(this).removeClass("hovereD"); });
        //even this is working
        z.each(function () {               
           if (parseInt($(this).text()) == parseInt($(x).val())) {
                $(this).addClass('activeD');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('activeD')
            }
        });
        //this code is not working
        z.click( function () {
            alert(this.innerText);
        // also tried alert($(this).text());
        });
        //even this code is not working
        z.on('click', function () {
            alert(this.innerText);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding click function inside a ready callback

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('td').click(function () {
        alert(this.innerText);
      });
    });
```